# iPhone UITableViewController move only specific rows in a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a standard `UITableViewController`. I have made only some rows in the table to be moveable, ie. `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` returns true only for some indexPaths (for rows in the first part of the table). I would like to allow exchange of only those rows that are moveable, ie. for which `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` returns true.

Eg. my table looks like this:

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
```

Rows 1, 2, 3 are moveable. So I want to implement the following behavior: row 1 can be exchanged only with rows 2 or 3. Similary, row 2 can be exchanged only with rows 1 and 3.
This is one possible layout:

```
Row 3
Row 1
Row 2
Row 4
Row 5
```

However, I don't want this to happen:

```
Row 3
Row 5
Row 2
Row 4
Row 1
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that it's actually only moving one row, not *exchanging*.

What you want is to implement `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath`

See [How to limit UITableView row reordering to a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849926/how-to-limit-uitableview-row-reordering-to-a-section)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the movement within section and between section.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

{

```
// Do not allow any movement between section
if ( sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section)
    return sourceIndexPath;
// You can even control the movement of specific row within a section. e.g last row in a     Section

// Check if we have selected the last row in section
if (   sourceIndexPath.row < sourceIndexPath.length) {
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
} else {
    return sourceIndexPath;
}
```

// you can use this approach or logic to check the index of the rows in section and return either sourceIndexPath or targetIndexPath

}