# UITableViewCell- controlling movement

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegation

When editing my UITableView, I give the option to move cells to reorder the data. However, The top two cells in the table are cells that give information about all of the cells in the table, and I dont want the user to be able to move information cells into that section. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: The user shouldn't be able to drag the cell titled 'This is bad!!!' into the section with the 'Total:' and 'New Group...' cells.]

The user shouldn't be able to drag the cell titled 'This is bad!!!' into the section with the 'Total:' and 'New Group...' cells. Is there a way to control this functionality? I haven't seen a delegate method that does this, but I could have missed one.

Edit: oops! I just saw that someone else has asked the same question on SO, so I'm going to post the link and close this question. Thanks @fzwo for your help.

[How to limit UITableView row reordering to a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849926/how-to-limit-uitableview-row-reordering-to-a-section)

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment because I've never tried it, but `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` from `UITableViewDelegate` looks like it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` from `UITableViewDelegate` is what you're looking for.

In your concrete case, you could also display the header information in the actual `tableView.tableHeaderView`. This scrolls like an ordinary cell, but isn't a cell. It would probably also make sense from a UI perspective, because it is something different than your ordinary cell content.

Comment: tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: is exactly for this particular question. This method is also good, but why overcomplicate things?

Comment: Because he doesn't want to restrict where to move *from*, but *to* - oh, or does this also restrict that? I haven't used it in a while, to be honest.