# Enable UITableView edit only in a specified section

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView with 4 sections. I want to enable editing (move/drag/ rearrange ) the cells only within the forth section. When I set: `tableView.editing = YES` I get all the table view to be in editing mode. This [How to limit UITableView row reordering to a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849926/how-to-limit-uitableview-row-reordering-to-a-section) helped me as I can now rearrange cells from a section only within their "root" section.

What I mean is if the cell is in the 1st section then I only get to rearrange within the 1st section and not the others. My goal is to enable editing only with The 4th section therefore putting in Move/drag Mode only the cells within the 4th Section. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing this delegate method

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shorter version: `return indexPath.section == 3`. :)

Comment: @tkanzakic do you know how i can log the new arrangement of cells?

Comment: @tkanzakic The arrangement will construct a new array which will reflect to a button arrangement. e.g. cell: 1,2,3 will arrange buttons in another view according to 1,2,3 (buttons: a,b,c). If the arrangement is 2,3,1 then the buttons will be sort: b,c,a..

Comment: you can assign a tag to each of the cell with the number you want and then use it

Comment: It's better to use enums instead of magic numbers:
    `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyControllerSection) {
        MyControllerSection1,...
        MyControllerSectionN,

        MyControllerSectionCount,
    };`

and then

    `return indexPath.section == MyControllerSection3;` ;-)