# UITableView like Social section in Contacts ios 7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I want to set functionality like add or remove new social profile in contact, in my table view. here I attached screenshot. please any one help me on this . [image: want to set this kind of functionality in my tableview]

Comment: Any one specify why the negative vote ..

Comment: I'm guessing the down vote is because you didn't include what you've tried already.

Comment: I worked around add and delete row functionality but its not worked looked like above.

Comment: I guess the negative vote is because you haven't given any code or specified exactly where in your project, you're having a problem

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code or include the details what you've tried already.

However there are many [custom tableview controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=table) are available.

Please look at [MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mscmoreoptiontableviewcell) for iOS and customize a little bit to achieve your goal.

[image]

Also please look at the [developer.apple - CreateConfigureTableView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html) and [Customize Cells.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

I think its very easy approach. 
1. Just have your add cell in second section of your table view 
2. Then enable editing in table view
3. when user tap the add more cell just add new cell in section 1.

The delete action will take care of by default behavior. its easy to disable delete for section.

[Enable UITableView edit only in a specified section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958149/enable-uitableview-edit-only-in-a-specified-section)

for changing the default delete icon refer this but this is not necessary.

[Change default icon for moving cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603359/change-default-icon-for-moving-cells-in-uitableview)

I think there is no need of code.