# Create array from NSSet in order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nsset

I am trying to create an array from an existing `NSSet`, but I can't find a method that creates the array in order. The only method I found was `allObjects`, but this method returns an array without a specified order (random indexes). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `allObjects` to get unsorted array, then use `descriptor` to do the sort stuff. For example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type1.size" ascending:YES];
NSArray *finalArray = [self.firstArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: What if I need the user to do the sorting part? Wouldn't setting an NSSortDescriptor prevent the user from doing this?

Comment: @rodrigochousal You mean the NSSet is already be sorted by User, what you wanna do is that just to convert NSSet to NSArray?

Comment: I want to use the array from the NSSet to create a tableView, but the user needs to be able to modify the order of the cells at any time.

Comment: @rodrigochousal Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

Comment: @rodrigochousal I think the original question is not the point. The point for you is how to refresh the datasource array after user resort the cells. You can refer to this also :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585736/uitableview-move-cell-to-a-position-to-another-with-drag-drop.

Comment: Not sure a moderator deleted my answer, but anyway Swift 3 now has a way of doing this:

    yourNSSetType?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "keyToSortBy", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSNumber.compare(_:)))]) as! [yourNSSetType]

For strings, use NSString.compare in the #selector call.