# Problem while rearranging table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app like Image Gallery. Of course, It has 2 sections.. I mean activeImageGalleries and recentlyDeletedImageGalleries

my table view cell can be rearranged, but I want it just rearrange on its section, not others section.. but it doesn't work

here is my code:

```
@IBAction func onEditing(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    if fromIndexPath.section != to.section {
        return
    }

    if fromIndexPath.section == 0 {
        let sourceImageGallery = activeImageGalleries.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        activeImageGalleries.insert(sourceImageGallery, at: to.row)
    }else {
        let sourceImageGallery = recentlyDeletedImageGalleries.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        recentlyDeletedImageGalleries.insert(sourceImageGallery, at: to.row)
    }

}
```

anybody know how to fix that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/849958/986169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit UITableView row reordering to a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849926/how-to-limit-uitableview-row-reordering-to-a-section)